# Splide Svelte customize pagination or any splide element in svelte component

Tags: html, css, svelte, splidejs

I am trying to use Splide in my **Svelte** aplication and I want to change where the pagination appears, since it is on top of my images and too transparent. I'm using [Svelte Splide](https://splidejs.com/integration/svelte-splide/) to implement this library and I was trying to follow the docs in order to customize elements from the splide.

I was able to set my styles on a `css` file that I just had to import and it worked. The problem is this does not seem like the ideal way to do it, I want to be able to set styles from the `styles` section in my component file.

This is my carousel component:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { Splide, SplideSlide, SplideTrack } from '@splidejs/svelte-splide';
    import type { Options } from '@splidejs/svelte-splide';
    import '@splidejs/svelte-splide/css';
    import './carousel-style.css'

    export let images: string[];

    let splideOptions: Options = {
        type: 'loop',
        perPage: 3,
        focus: 0,
        gap: '1rem',
        padding: '1em',
        breakpoints: {
            640: { perPage: 1, perMove: 1, arrows: false },
            1024: { perPage: 2, perMove: 1 }
        }
    };
</script>

<Splide hasTrack={false} pagination options={splideOptions}>
    <SplideTrack>
        {#each images as image}
            <SplideSlide>
                <img class="m-auto" src={image} alt="Aglo" />
            </SplideSlide>
        {/each}
    </SplideTrack>
    <ul class="splide__pagination" />
</Splide>

<style>
    .splide__pagination__page.is-active {
        background: blue;
    }
    .splide__pagination.splide__pagination__page {
        background-color: black;
    }
</style>
```

The css is the same as in `carousel-style.css`. I think the reazon it's not working is because the classes are never declared on my component, which is why if I try appling css to the class `splide__pagination` it does work, but for it's children it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do resolve this by using the `global()` selector like so:

```html
<style>
    .splide__pagination :global(.splide__pagination__page.is-active) {
        background-color: blue
    }
    .splide__pagination :global(.splide__pagination__page) {
        background-color: black;
    }
</style>
```